# Any way to show image of a star instead of a RadioButton

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

in WPF ?

sorry this is a basic question, still learning the basics here !

Answer (score 4):

Copy/Paste/Run this silly sample :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Polygon x:Name="star" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Points="18,4 22,14 35,14 24,20 28,30 18,24 8,30 12,20 2,14 14,14"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="RadioButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Polygon.Fill" Value="Gold"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="one" GroupName="sillySample" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton Content="two" GroupName="sillySample"/>
    <RadioButton Content="tree" GroupName="sillySample"/>
</StackPanel>
```

in short, in WPF you can override some control template to swap internal control structure with whatever you want, yet keeping it's behavior, as I did here (just to demonstrate this exact point) I am using RadioButton.IsChecked property to set the Fill to Gold, as it (IsChecked) doesn't belong to either textblock or polygon, however I am still able to use it since I am overriding RadioButton's template

Anyway, good luck

denis

Answer (score -1):

yes you can. the thing is you have to create a xaml style for radiobutton

Comment: any sample would be very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You could replace the control template.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_controltemplates